# angular ngClipboard copy text in service response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a service inside ngclick function and I want to copy the  service's response. I am using ng-clickboard http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-clipboard

Here's my code.

**View:-**

> `<a ng-click="copytext()"></a>`

**Controller:-**

> ```
> this.copytext = function () {   
>      GalleryAddService.getCampaignHash()
>             .success(function (response) {
>                 if (response) {                 
>                    ngClipboard.toClipboard(response);
>                 }
>          }); };
> ```

When I am using ngClipboard.toClipboard function outside the service call and exact after the copytext function then it's working fine but don't know why not inside the service response.

Comment: Sonia ,are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this message "Copying text command was unsuccessful"

Comment: i am facing the same issue. is any solution available?